# Dense linear span implies injectivity of a Gelfand Transform

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital commutative Banach Algebra.

Let $\Omega(A)$ be the set of non-zero homomorphisms from $A$ to $\Bbb C$.

Suppose the set of idempotents $N$ in $A$ have dense linear span.

Show the map $f:\Omega(A)\rightarrow \{0,1\}^N$ defined by $f(\phi)(e) = \phi(e)$ is injective.

In [The spectrum of a commutative unital Banach algbra having linearly dense idempotents is totally disconnected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432896/the-spectrum-of-a-commutative-unital-banach-algbra-having-linearly-dense-idempot?rq=1), it says that the injectivity comes from the dense linear span. But I don't really see how this goes.

So if $f(\phi)(e) =f (\psi)(e)$ , we have $\phi(e)=\psi(e)$. Why does the dense linear span tell us $\phi=\psi$?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi(e)=\psi (e)$,  for every idempotent $e$,  then  $\phi(a)=\psi (a)$,  for every element $a$ which can be written as
a linear combination of idempotents (because $\phi$ and $\psi $ are linear).

The set of all such $a$ is suposedly dense,  so $\phi$ and $\psi $ coincide on a dense set,  and hence everywhere because
they are continuous.